# Draw PieChart with triangle in the middle of PieChart slice

Tags: java, swing, draw, pie-chart, paintcomponent

I want to draw a piechart with a triangle in the middle of the piechart slice.
At the moment I draw a piechat with slices and triangles in the middle of the slices, but the triangles are not in the right angle. I need to know how to position the triangles in the right way. My Code and the result:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.*;

class Slice {

   double value;
   Color color;
   public Slice(double value, Color color) {  
      this.value = value;
      this.color = color;
   }
}

class PieChart extends JPanel {

    private Color a = Color.RED;
    private Color b = Color.BLUE;
    private Color c = Color.YELLOW;
    Slice[] slices = { 
               new Slice(60, a),
               new Slice(100, b),
               new Slice(200, c)
    };

    public PieChart(){

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        super.paintComponent(g2d);
        this.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        double total = 0.0D;
        for (int i = 0; i < slices.length; i++) {
            total += slices[i].value;
        }

        double curValue = 90.0D;
        int startAngle = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < slices.length; i++) {
            startAngle = (int) (curValue * 360 / total);
            int arcAngle = (int) (slices[i].value * 360 / total);
            g2d.setColor(slices[i].color);
            g2d.fillArc(20, 20, 200, 200, startAngle, arcAngle);

            g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
            int x = (int)(110+100*Math.cos(((-(startAngle+(arcAngle/2)))*Math.PI)/180));
            int y = (int)(110+100*Math.sin(((-(startAngle+(arcAngle/2)))*Math.PI)/180));

            Polygon p = new Polygon(new int[] {x, x+14, x+7}, new int[] {y, y, y-14}, 3); // this values seems to be important
            g2d.draw(p);
            g2d.fill(p);

            curValue += slices[i].value;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Edit: should look like this:

[image]

Comment: It would be nice to see picture with *desired* triangles positions. Right now it is not quite clear, what do you want to achieve.

Comment: If I see this correctly, you want the base of the triangle to be tangent to the center point of the sector's arc. They will touch in one point. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the first arc to start from 0 o'clock (I think you meant to do this).

Since you are using `fillArc` which takes `int`s, the rounded down `double`s might not add up to the full amount and you will have gaps between the slices:

[image]

Instead, use `Arc2D.Double` to get better precision:

[image]

```
class Slice {

    double value;
    Color color;

    public Slice(double value, Color color) {

        this.value = value;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Color getColor() {

        return color;
    }

    public double getValue() {

        return value;
    }
}

class PieChart extends JPanel {

    private final int SIZE = 500, START = 40, START_DEG = 90;
    private final int TRIG_HBASE = 66, TRIG_HEIGHT = 36;
    private final int x0 =(START + SIZE / 2), y0 = START;
    private final Polygon poly;

    private Color a = Color.RED;
    private Color b = Color.BLUE;
    private Color c = Color.YELLOW;
    Slice[] slices = {new Slice(65, a), new Slice(123, b), new Slice(212, c)};

    PieChart() {

        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        int x1 = x0 + TRIG_HBASE,  y1 = y0;
        int x2 = x0 - TRIG_HBASE,  y2 = y0;
        int x3 = x0,               y3 = y0 - TRIG_HEIGHT;
        poly = new Polygon(new int[] {x1, x2, x3}, new int[] {y1, y2, y3}, 3);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g2d);

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2d.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g2d.fillRect(START, START, SIZE, SIZE);

        double total = 0d;
        for (Slice slice : slices) {
            total += slice.getValue();
        }

        double startAngle = START_DEG;
        double arcAngle, centerAngle;
        double x, y;

        for (Slice slice : slices) {
            arcAngle = (slice.getValue() * 360 / total);
            g2d.setColor(slice.getColor());
            g2d.fill(new Arc2D.Double(START, START, SIZE, SIZE, startAngle, arcAngle, Arc2D.PIE));

            centerAngle = Math.toRadians(((startAngle - START_DEG) + arcAngle / 2));
            x = (START + SIZE / 2 * (1 - Math.sin(centerAngle)));
            y = (START + SIZE / 2 * (1 - Math.cos(centerAngle)));

            AffineTransform trans = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x - x0, y - y0);
            AffineTransform rot = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(-centerAngle, x, y);
            Shape s = trans.createTransformedShape(poly);
            s = rot.createTransformedShape(s);

            g2d.setColor(slice.getColor().darker());
            g2d.fill(s);

            startAngle += arcAngle;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {

        return new Dimension(START * 2 + SIZE, START * 2 + SIZE);
    }
}
```

`poly` serves as the basic triangle and is facing upwards with its base centered on the 0 o'clock point. Each arc translates and transforms (a copy of) this polygon so that its base is centered at the center of the arc length and so that it points outwards.

**Notes:**

- Don't call `setBackground` inside `paintComponent`, call it outside. It causes the paint mechanism to automatically paint the background on each repaint. If you put it inside you are just overriding the instruction with every repaint. Alternatively, you can use `g.clearRect` to set the background to white (or `fillRect` for a different color).
- Override the panel's `getPreferredSize` method to be compatible with its contents.
- Work with constants (`final`) instead of inline numbers. This way you only need to change them in one place and all dependencies are accounted for.
- Slice could use getter methods (generally preferred over direct field access), and it also allows `for each` loops.
- Work with `double`s and only convert to `int` at the latest point, otherwise you lose precision (you convert your angles to `int` and then use them as a `double` argument).
- `Math.toRadians` and `Math.toDegrees` are worth being acquainted with.
- I made the triangles wide to show how they intersect with the arcs, change the `TRIG` constants to play with their sizes. I also colored them to know which triangle belongs to which arc.
- I added a background to the arcs just to see the perimeter better.

---

Here is the result with your parameters (and no special coloring):

```
private final int SIZE = 200, START = 20, START_DEG = 90;
private final int TRIG_HBASE = 7, TRIG_HEIGHT = 14;
```

[image]

Comment: very very very helpfull answer and thanks a lot for the given tips! As an Java starter this is the best way to get an answer!

Comment: Edit: is there a reason for the constructor to be set as "no public" ?

Comment: @Linda No, I just added code to the empty constructor you gave in your code. See my profile for my answers' policy, visibility is something you need to set according to the bigger picture, a snippet of code can't tell us what's best.

Answer (score 1):

Here I made a solution (change the algorithm a little bit):

```
public class Chart {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame= new JFrame();
    frame.add(new PieChart());
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    EventQueue.invokeLater( () ->{
        frame.setVisible(true);
    });
}

public static class Slice {
    double value;
    Color color;

    public Slice(double value, Color color) {
        this.value = value;
        this.color = color;
    }
}

public static class  PieChart extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Color a = Color.RED;
    private Color b = Color.BLUE;
    private Color c = Color.YELLOW;
    Slice[] slices = { new Slice(60, a), new Slice(100, b),
            new Slice(200, c) };

    public PieChart() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g2d);

        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        int upperLeftX = 20;
        int upperLeftY = 20;
        int r = 100;
        int startAngle = 0;


        double curValue = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < slices.length; i++) {
            startAngle = (int) curValue ;
            int arcAngle = (int) slices[i].value ;
            g2d.setColor(slices[i].color);
            g2d.fillArc(upperLeftX, upperLeftY, r*2, r*2, startAngle, arcAngle);

            g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);

            double qi = curValue+slices[i].value/2;

            int x = upperLeftX + r + (int)(Math.cos(qi*Math.PI/180)*r);
            int y = upperLeftY + r - (int)(Math.sin(qi*Math.PI/180)*r);
            //point touching the circle (x,y)->half point of the base               
            int x1 = x - (int)(7*Math.sin(qi*Math.PI/180));
            int y1 = y - (int)(7*Math.cos(qi*Math.PI/180));

            int x2 = x + (int)(7*Math.sin(qi*Math.PI/180));
            int y2 = y + (int)(7*Math.cos(qi*Math.PI/180));

            int x3 = upperLeftX + r + (int)(Math.cos(qi*Math.PI/180)*(r+12));
            int y3 = upperLeftY + r - (int)(Math.sin(qi*Math.PI/180)*(r+12));


            Polygon p = new Polygon(new int[] { x1, x2, x3  },
                    new int[] { y1, y2, y3 }, 3); // this values seems to
                                                    // be important

            g2d.draw(p);
            g2d.fill(p);

            curValue += slices[i].value;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working if I change the slice sizes, e.g. `{63, 112, 212}`. And with `{60, 70, 80}` the arcs don't fill the pie chart.

Comment: General tip: when you say something like "*change the algorithm a little bit*" you will want to explain what you did, otherwise it's not an answer as much as it is "here, have some code" even if the solution is prefect.

Comment: Tip noted :) . With the values: 63,112,212 the sum of the values is more then 360 that is why it seems to be of (they are actually well positioned just the yellow part got drawn over the red one). In the other case the sum is less then 360 and that is why the arch is not fully filled. I did not touch the arch drawing part of the logic(other then extracting the values into variables) since the question was about triangle positioning.

Comment: From the OP's code it seems to me that the values don't need to add to 360 as they only specify weights. `6, 10, 20`, `60, 100, 200` and `600, 1000, 2000` should all give the same proportions.